# How to check if ldap connection is secured?

Tags: .net, ssl, ldap, wireshark

How can I know If ldap connection is really secured by SSL or not, using ldp and using .net code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to test if I’m connecting secured or not by using Wireshark.
you can set the filter there to something like : tcp.port eq 636 or tcp.port eq 389
so you will see the communication through 636 and 389 ports.

My conclusion is that the ldap server uses a secured connection on 636 port even if ssl is not checked in the ldp, checking it has no effect if port 636 is set.

I think this checkbox purpose is to force ssl by the client, so if ssl is not supported in the port by the server, connection will not be established.

When I use a secured connection from my c# code it defaults to port 636 and when it’s not secured it defaults to 389.

The way to use a secure connection from the code is either to set the connection authentication type to ssl or specify the ssl port in the ldap path.

Comment: All that depends entirely on how the LDAP server is configured. What you have described is certainly the normal state, but you've overlooked STARTTLS via port 389, which is secure.

Comment: Finding myself go through these exercises these days, and just typing `ldap` as the WireShark filter gives you the actual LDAP traffic you're looking for. When SASL is in use, you can tell if it provides either integrity protection (`SASL GSS-API Integrity`) and/or privacy protection (`SASL GSS-API Privacy`). These two are [NOT the same](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/123478/21509), however.

Comment: @Terry Gardner's answer is more correct in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

The port number has nothing to do with it. 389 is the standards-defined port for non-secure LDAP connections and 636 is the standards-defined port for secure connections. Most servers can be configured to use any port as secure and any other port as non-secure. 389 and 636 are simply standards-based defaults. A server can be configured to use 636 as the non-secure port and 389 as the secure port - although this would be a counter-intuitive configuration violating standards. Additionally, the connection on 389 can be promoted to a secure connection using StartTLS so 389 could also be secure.

Comment: I know ports can be set differently. My answer is based on the default settings. If different settings are set, you should change them in the answer accordingly. But thanks for the clarification.
By the way I still haven't tested a case when trying to connect from the code secured but the port in the server is set to a different port than 636. I assume in that case the connection will fail and you I will have to set the port manually.

Comment: The Root DSE may provide attributes to tell the clients about the security and the secure ports the LDAP server is using. For example, IBM Tivoli Directory Server provides the following attributes that may help an LDAP client to find out the secure ports:

secureport: 636
security: ssltls
port: 389

Of course, not all LDAP vendors provide this information in Root DSE and even if they did, you'd still have to know the non-secure port to retrieve the Root DSE.

Comment: I confirmed that setting AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer in the DirectoryEntry object in the .net code without specifying the port in the ldap path cause the connection to use port 636, so if a different port is set in the ldap server for ldaps, it most be specified in the ldap path. And if connecting unsecured, without specifying the port, .net will try to connect on port 389.